# config.lua for screen sizes (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, ios, iphone, lua, coronasdk

I made a game with Corona on portrait mode. Everything is great, but config is not adaptable for all different screen sizes. This is my code:

```
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth

application = {
   content = {
      width = aspectRatio > 1.5 and 320 or math.floor( 480 / aspectRatio ),
      height = aspectRatio < 1.5 and 480 or math.floor( 320 * aspectRatio ),
      scale = "letterBox",
      fps = 60,

      imageSuffix = {
         ["@2x"] = 1.5,
         ["@4x"] = 3.0,
      },
   },
}
```

for example: all iPhone models is fine with this code, but not for iPhone 4. (elements of game is above screen). Is there any " universal " code or?

I hope that someone can help me.

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content area should always be defined in respect to portrait orientation. And iPhone 4 aspectRatio is 1.5, so you are changing the width and height. Keep always 320x480.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html